# subquery factoring cannot work in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

when I am using postgresql, I encounter a problem.Here is the code:

```
    WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
    TABLE_NAME AS TABELA
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'nu_cns' )
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME IN t1
```

If I run it ,I will get a error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t1"
LINE 14:  TABLE_NAME IN t1
                    ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 211
```

But what is weird is that if I replace the t1 with the whole subquery ,it can run successfully, like this:

```
    WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
    TABLE_NAME AS TABELA
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'nu_cns' )
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME IN (
    SELECT
    TABLE_NAME AS TABELA
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'nu_cns' )
```

You see, in fact the subquery is exactly same with the t1.So why the former cannot work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below: you need to select table_name from t1 in subquery

```
WITH t1 AS 
( 
  SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABELA
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'nu_cns' 
)

SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (select table_name from t1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just mistakenly thought that the t1 is already the select result of table.But in fact it's only a table name...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1 AS 
( 
  SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABELA
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'nu_cns' 
)

SELECT 
    t2.TABLE_NAME,
    t2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2 join t1 on t1.TABELA = t2.table_name
```

Comment: could you explain to us what this sql does?